# Apps Script: transfer owner of standalone script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a standalone Apps Script (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) that I need to transfer to someone else to manage. I don't see an option to share the script and to transfer ownership. Does anyone know how I should go about doing that?

Comment: If you share a file with edit permissions, the person it is shared with can make a copy.  The copy will be owned by the account that made the copy.  If the file is a web app, the new owner would need to publish the web app, and it would have a different URL.  This isn't really a programming question, or a question about the code editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can share the script in the top-right corner using the Share button.
After you've shared it you (as the owner) can make someone else owner.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

You could make a copy of the standalone script on your own drive and then change the ownership

```
    function copyScript(){
    var scriptCopy = DriveApp.getFileById("yourScriptID").makeCopy().setName('ScriptCopyName');
    DriveApp.getFileById(scriptCopy.getId()).setOwner('emailAddress')
}
```